# Future perfect continuous or future continuous?

Tags: difference, future-tense, future-perfect, future-continuous

Which variant is correct?

> Will you still be living here in ten years?

Or

> Will you still have been living here in ten years?

Please help me see the difference between the two sentences.

Answer (score 0):

> Will you still be living here in ten years?

is correct. The question should ask about your state at some point in the future rather than your state leading up to that point.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In that case, Will you still live? may also be correct or not?

Comment: If so, Will you still live? may also be correct? Taking into consideration that to live is a non-terminative verb. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Will you still live here?" could also be correct.